# Converting among pointers-to-member

Tags: c++, casting, pointer-to-member

I know you can't convert a pointer-to-member to a pointer-to-non-member (e.g., `void*`), but can you convert among pointers-to-member for the same class?  E.g.: for some class `C` and types `T` and `U`, can you convert a `T C::*` to a `U C::*`?

I want to be able to map string names to pointers-to-member for some class. For example, given:

```
template<class ClassType>
struct mbr_map_traits {
    typedef std::string mbr_name_type;
    typedef void* ClassType::*any_mbr_ptr;
    typedef std::map<mbr_name_type,any_mbr_ptr> map_type;
};

/**
 * A %mbr_map is used to map a string to an arbitrary pointer-to-member of some class.
 * @tparam ClassType The class whose members to map to.
 */
template<class ClassType>
struct mbr_map : mbr_map_traits<ClassType>::map_type {
    typedef typename mbr_map_traits<ClassType>::mbr_name_type mbr_name_type;

    /**
     * Initalizes an entry in the map so as to mape \a name to a pointer-to-member.
     * @param name The name to map.
     * @param p    The pointer-to-member to map to.
     */
    template<typename MemberType>
    void mbr_init( mbr_name_type const &name, MemberType ClassType::*p ) {
        typedef typename mbr_map_traits<ClassType>::any_mbr_ptr any_mbr_ptr;
        (*this)[ name ] = reinterpret_cast<any_mbr_ptr>( p );      // IS THIS OK?
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of a class member by name.
     * @param c     The class whose member to set.
     * @param name  The name of the class member to set.
     * @param value The value to set the member to.
     * @return true only if \a name exists in the map.
     */
    template<typename MemberType>
    bool mbr_set( ClassType &c, mbr_name_type const &name, MemberType const &value ) {
        typedef typename mbr_map<ClassType>::const_iterator const_iterator;
        const_iterator const found = this->find( name );
        if ( found != this->end() ) {
            typedef MemberType ClassType::*mbr_ptr;
            c.*reinterpret_cast<mbr_ptr>( found->second ) = value; // IS THIS OK?
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

and some one-time initialization:

```
struct S {
    std::string s;
    int i;
    bool b;
};

void mbr_map_init( mbr_map<S> *m ) {
    m->mbr_init( "string_mbr", &S::s );
    m->mbr_init( "int_mbr", &S::i );
    m->mbr_init( "bool_mbr", &S::b );
}
```

I can do this:

```
using namespace std;

int main() {
    mbr_map<S> m;
    mbr_map_init( &m );

    S s;

    m.mbr_set( s, "string_mbr", string( "hello" ) );
    m.mbr_set( s, "int_mbr", 42 );
    m.mbr_set( s, "bool_mbr", true );

    cout << s.s << endl;
    cout << s.i << endl;
    cout << s.b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and it prints the values I set. But is this *legal*?

(The reason I want to do something like this is to map parameter names and values read from a configuration file to structure members.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you make a cast back to the original type before using the pointer-to-member there is no problem.

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast description of reinterpret_cast:

> .... It is purely a compiler directive which instructs the compiler to treat the sequence of bits (object representation) of expression as if it had the type new_type.
>
> Only the following conversions can be done....
>
> 1) An expression of integral, enumeration, pointer, or **pointer-to-member** type can be converted to its own type. **The resulting value is the same as the value of expression.**

So cast a pointer-to-member of type string to pointer-to-member of type OtherType and then at a later point casting the same pointer-to-member of type OtherType back to pointer-to-member of type string is perfectly good and won't change the original value of the pointer-to-member.

Answer (score 0):

> for some class C and types T and U, can you convert a **T C::*** to a
>   **U C::***?

Short answer is yes.

Long answer is of course. Data pointers, of whatever type, just give you an offset to the actual data within a structure. Type information is not encoded in the pointer - the datatype is external to actual pointer value.

Needless to say, your code is a little *hairy*.

Comment: So how would you do it?

Comment: I wouldn't trust some random user input to specify type. You can stringify names with preprocessor and use it to associate names with types and fields, which is done at compile time. At runtime you just have some specialized type parser that is associated with a name. No reinterpret casts anywhere, and no type guessing mbr_set. But if you want to keep your map, at very least check that the type is the same. For example, you can use boost::any for that, or std::type_info

Comment: My code, as written, does hard-code the names and types. The user input comes only from the conf files that, by definition, have to be user configurable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is legal.  In the description for `reinterpret_cast`, the language spec says,

> A prvalue of type “pointer to member of X of type T1” can be explicitly converted to a prvalue of a different type “pointer to member of Y of type T2” if T1 and T2 are both function types or both object types. ... The
>   result of this conversion is unspecified, except [converting a pointer-to-member to another pointer-to-member and back gives the original pointer to member value].

So it is allowed but may or may not do what you expect it to.